# Is there any way to modify a webcam from command prompt

Tags: windows, webcam

I got a life cam HD 5000 webcam and I want it to be used for programming stuff , In Ubuntu terminal you have the ability to change the webcams settings (after installing something) , because my code must be run on windows is there any way (any installation or anything) to modify webcams lie Ubuntu ?

Comment: From the command prompt, no, from your own process you wrote of course.